# statically linking libs. c compilation

Tags: c, linux, static, libraries, ncurses

I am working on a program which uses ncurses which will be used on embedded systems. Since these systems won't have ncurses installed I need to statically link the library. However if I try to build it like this

```
gcc -static ncurs.c -o ncurs -l:libncurses.a
```

or

```
gcc -static ncurs.c -o ncurs -lncurses
```

I get a ton of errors like this:

```
(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `SP'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.a(lib_slktouch.o): In function `slk_touch':
```

normal compilation works fine.

I have searched for hours but I can't find any good information...

platform of development is stripped down debian system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you may need additional library, can you try `-lncurses -ltinfo`.

You can check on your system what the linker library flags for `ncurses` using command

```
pkg-config --static --libs ncurses
```

on my system, I got

```
-lncurses -ltinfo
```

Comment: wow thanks this was the solution to my problem, would you mind explaining what -ltinfo is for?

Comment: It's another library, libtinfo

Answer (score 0):

try adding `-ltinfo` to the end of your commandline